# Office freezes whenever a file picker appears

Tags: microsoft-office, freeze

Yesterday, I was working on a PowerPoint template for my dad that had some image placeholders in it (You know, the ones where you click on them to open a file picker to choose the image). When testing the template, PowerPoint froze whenever I'd try to select an image. This would happen after my first interaction with the file browser (selecting a file, moving the window, changing directory, etc).

At first, I thought this was some bug with the image selector popup. Dragging an image into PowerPoint still works so I went on my way. However, I later found that all my Office programs freeze when I open their respective file browsers, be it to save a file, open a file, select an image or do whatever else requires a file browser.

After freezing, the program will stay in the background until I force close it from task manager.

I'm running Office version 1703 (Build 7967.2161) x32

EDIT:

I sometimes get the following pop-up when it happens:

> ### POWERPNT.EXE - Application Error
>
> The exception unknown software exception (0xe0000002) occurred in the application at location 0x000000007726B802.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: From a similar issue with an unrelated app a while ago - do you have anything installed that adds overlays to icons - OneDrive, DropBox etc ?

Comment: I do have OneDrive (I don't think you can get rid of it?) and Google Drive installed. However, this issue seems to also occur when I try to save to, or open from a directory that is not inside such a directory. For example, I also get the issue when trying to navigate to my downloads folder.

Comment: Best I can do, I'm afraid. The previous issue caused a malloc error & the fix had to come from Microsoft. The workaround was to uninstall OneDrive/SkyDrive/DropBox or disable the overlays - navigating to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` & disabling them there. I can't say whether that would fix this issue, but you could test it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I found [these entries](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/lape69a0632a19c00eef263709f3649e57b.png). All the different entries have a "(default)" entry with some guid value. What exactly should I disable?

Comment: Trash all the subfolders OneDrive1... SkyDrivePro1 etc [you might want to backup the reg keys first, in case it doesn't fix it]

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't fix it. My desktop computer at home is also suffering from the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was a stab in the dark :/